# STM32F4 - Sensor data processing - ADC -> USB/Ethernet -> PC - USB Oscilloscope

Tags: matlab, stm32, simulink, sensors, adc

I am currently working on a project about "Digitization of sensor signals". The sensor signal is to be digitized with an ADC and passed on to the PC via an interface, e.g. USB or Ethernet. Ideally, the ADC works in continuous mode at 2 megasample/s and 12 bit. The amount of data that occurs during continuous digitization will probably only be manageable via Ethernet. Alternatively, discontinuous recording with 5ms recording each and a pause of 45ms.

Currently I use a Nucleo-F429ZI. Programming can be done via HAL or Matlab/Simulink. Matlab Simulink provides a suitable GUI for programming, among other things for Ethernet. However, the GUI is not available for all Nucleo boards. Unfortunately, the F429ZI is not supported.

I am currently considering how best to implement the project. I would like to process the digitized data afterwards also by Matlab. In this respect, it would make sense to carry out the programming in Simulink. For this I would also be willing to switch to another board.

I already have experience with Matlab, but less with programming in HAL. What would you advise me? Do you have any other tips?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If your ADC works at 2MSa/s in 12bit resolution and if you use uint16_t for storing data samples, you need 4MB/s (or 32Mbit/s) connection with a PC. STM32F429 has a hardware peripheral for USB High Speed, that can theoretically achieve 480Mbit/s, so much more than is needed.

Personally, I would try using USB in VCP (Virtual COM Port) mode, that is detected as a simple COM port in a PC, just like Arduino or any device with serial port, but is much faster. Then you can read data from it in real time to Matlab script or save it in log file for further processing.

Most efficient way would be to start ADC in DMA mode with dual buffer. While one buffer is filled by ADC+DMA, the second one is transmitted via USB. This leaves plenty of time for CPU to handle data transmission, but it has to wait until entire buffer is filled. You can trigger ADC conversion with timer, so sampling time will be consistent - only data transmission will occur in chunks.

If you have possibility to get board that is compatible with environment that you are experienced with - definitely go for it. Starting USB, ADC, DMA and timers is not trivial to someone who has little experience with low-level programming.

This all comes down to your personal skills in embedded programming and time that you can spend on this project.

Comment: I can second that. I am actually working on an application with a STM32F4, that generates continuously approx. 1.2 MB/s of data and has to stream these data to a PC for visualization. I am simply using the USB_OTG_FS Peripheral (with 12Mbit/s) of the STM32F4 configured as “Device_Only” (virtual COM-Port). So far it works well and I have no issues. I use a “double buffer”-technique and send out the data with  >>CDC_Transmit_FS(buf, bufSz);<<

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I followed your advice and configured the USB as VCP. I send the data via CDC_Transmit. I have also applied the advice about double buffering. Very helpful was a tutorial from STM, which I followed. 

However, I still have a question of understanding. I am able to send the data via USB to my laptop. However, I am not yet able to read out the data. In Matlab I have to specify the baud rate for this. However, I have not defined the baud rate, because I have not defined one for the USB port.

Comment: Virtual COM port has no actual baudrate parameter because it is, well, virtual. When I used VCP with serial monitors like one in Arduino IDE I could set any baudrate and it always worked fine. So just try to pass any standard baudrate, like 115200, and it should work. 


When your VCP works as converter between USB and physical UART this baudrate is used to configure physical UART. This is a case in ST-Link programmers included with STM32 Nucleo development boards, for example.